# Why nginx add_headers doesn't work properly?

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I'm using Nginx as a web server.
This is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location ^~ /start/ {
        add_header 'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy' 'require-corp';
        add_header 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy' 'same-origin';
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

When I open this link on the browser, I don't see the header in the network tab in the response headers section:
`https://example.com/start/629852d359d2a400034698a2`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `add_header` directive works properly. Most probably headers does not get added since there are no `/usr/share/nginx/html/start/629852d359d2a400034698a2` file or directory on your server, so request gets rewritten to `/index.html` according to the last `try_files` directive parameter, which in turn being processed by your `location / { ... }` (since that new URI does not start with a `/start/` prefix), and that location does not set any additional headers.

---

Generally, if those `/start/`-prefixed URIs could be either internal application routes or external assets links, this would be possible to solve using the `map` block to evaluate required headers values:

```
map $uri $add_policies {
    ~^/start/  1;
    # default value will be an empty string, unless specified explicitly
}
map $add_policies $embedder_policy {
    1  require-corp;
}
map $add_policies $opener_policy {
    1  same-origin;
}
server {
    ...
    location / {
        add_header Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy $embedder_policy;
        add_header Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy $origin_policy;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

This solution is based on the `add_header` behavior, which is not to add the specified header to the response at all if the provided value is an empty string.

However, if you know for sure the URIs where those headers should be added are an app routes rather than links to physically existing files, you have one more option:

```
server {
    ...
    location ^~ /start/ {
        set $embedder_policy require-corp;
        set $origin_policy same-origin;
        rewrite ^ /index.html last;
    }
    location / {
        add_header Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy $embedder_policy;
        add_header Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy $origin_policy;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

This solution should be somewhat more performant since it does not require (some kind of expensive) PCRE library call to perform the regex matching operation.

**Update**

Reviewing my answers, I just figured out that the last configuration can be made even more simple using `rewrite ... break` instead of `rewrite ... last`:

```
server {
    ...
    location ^~ /start/ {
        add_header Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy require-corp;
        add_header Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy same-origin;
        rewrite ^ /index.html break;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan for answering!
How can I resolve that?

Comment: Sorry, resolve exactly what kind of problem? You didn't describe anything of your environment or web app being served, I don't know what does `/start/` URI suffix means here, is it a directory name containing another web app or a virtual route prefix, etc, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I have a SPA.
I just want to add those headers want in routes that start with `start/`.

Comment: So, everything starts with a `/start/` prefix should be considered as a SPA route (to be processed with the `/index.html` controller), right? It cannot be any of the SPA assets, so we can skip the check "is `$uri` an existing file/directory"?

Comment: `/start/` routes have been shown on a new window but have been handled with main SPA

Comment: Added an update to the answer.